# angular2 change of datepicker's date can't trigger ngModelChange

Tags: angular, angular-material2

In my html:

```
<input mdInput [(ngModel)]="start" (ngModelChange)="change()"
         [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="choose date">
<md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

and in my component.ts:

```
class Component {
  public start: Date;
  public change() {
    console.log(111);
  }
}
```

On the web page, if I click the toggle to change datepicker's date. It will print `111` in console. But if I change date in `ts` file with `this.start = new Date()`, it will not print `111`. But the datepicker on web page has changed.

Comment: because you are setting the default value of the ngModel  when the component loads

Comment: Because `111` is not a variable. you should log `console.log(start)` in `change` method.

Comment: @TouqeerShafi In fact, result of  ```111``` is the same with  ```this.start```.

Comment: @RahulSingh I remove the default value of ```start```. It can't work also.

Comment: how do you set this start can you show , by shared services of input bindings

Answer (score -2):

Try `(dateChange)="nameOfYourFunction($event)"`